# No such property: sonatypeRepo for class in android studio while importing project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

i have downloaded image cropper example from following link

https://github.com/edmodo/cropper

and when i try to import it in a android studio i am getting following error.

here is the error , i am quite new to this so m not aware how i resolve.

[image]

Have tried by importing project as gradle but same error

[image]

**inside master**

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        // Plug-in release notes: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.11.+'
        compile 'com.edmodo:cropper:1.0.1'

    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    // See latest Gradle version: http://www.gradle.org/downloads
    gradleVersion = '1.12'

}
```

**inside cropper**

```
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile project(':cropper')
}

android {

    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can import it in two ways.

**First method:**

*build.gradle*

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {    
    ...
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.edmodo:cropper:1.0.1'
}
```

**Second one:**

Download [cropper](https://github.com/edmodo/cropper).

Put *cropper* folder inside *projectname* directory.

Edit *settings.gradle*:

```
include ':app', ':cropper'
```

Edit *build.gradle*:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {    
    ...
}

dependencies {
    ...
    compile project(':cropper')
}
```

**Library Project:**

If you would like to use cropper as library project you need to do:

Clone cropper.

Import project (Eclipse ADT ...) using Android Studio.

Known error will appear after sync fail:

> Error:(47, 0) No such property: sonatypeRepo for class: org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.ant.DefaultGroovyMavenDeployer

Inside project root directory create *gradle.properties* with:

```
sonatypeUsername=
sonatypePassword=
sonatypeRepo=
```

Fix plugin version:

> Error:The project is using an unsupported version of the Android Gradle plug-in (0.11.2). The recommended version is 1.1.0.
>   Fix plugin version and re-import project

Now you will be able to run CropperSample project. Since cropper is now working you can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: i am getting following error `A problem occurred evaluating root project 'cropper-master'.
> Could not find method compile() for arguments [project ':cropper'] on org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler_Decorated@202a6eeb.`

Comment: @Hunt - can you post your gradle files?

Comment: I ran into the same problem ("No such property: sonatypeRepo for class.....").  I applied the Library Project solution and it fixed my problem as of gradle plugin v2.3.  This should be the selected answer.

Answer (score 4):

You should not put your application specific dependencies in the "master" build file. In your case, the master `build.gradle` file buildscript block should look like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.11.+'
    }
}
```

And then append this to the `build.gradle` file of the app where you want to use Cropper, in this case the CropperSample project:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.edmodo:cropper:1.0.1'
}
```

I noticed you added `compile project(':cropper')` to the `build.gradle` file of the Cropper project. This will not work because you are basically making the Cropper project depend on itself. If you want to download the code and use that instead of Maven Central, then you should add the dependency to CropperSample and remove that line from the Cropper project's build file.

Answer (score 1):

1] Download Cropper from https://github.com/edmodo/cropper

Unzip

> cropper-master.zip

2] Go to Android Studio  *File --> New --> Import Module*

Import Only *../cropper-maste/cropper*  folder

In Android Studio Project check **cropper** module added.

3] Goto cropper module's **buld.gradle**

Add comment or remove

```
uploadArchives {
       /* repository(url: sonatypeRepo) {
            authentication(userName: sonatypeUsername,
                    password: sonatypePassword)
        }*/

}
```

4] Goto Android Studio Project's **build.gradle**

Add dependencies

```
dependencies {
     compile project(':cropper')
}
```

5] Rebuild, Sync Gradle.